# Should I use batch normalization synchronization across multiple GPUs for classification training

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, batch-normalization

I'm wondering if for regular classification training it's crucial to use batch normalization synchronization when training on multiple GPUs. Many papers report improved model quality when training larger batches, this also include larger learning rates during training.
I'm not sure if this is only due to larger amount of images that is going into calculating the loss, of is it also important during calculating batch statistics.
For example in pytorch it would mean using SyncBatchNorm

Papers like "Big transfer learning" (https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.11370) are mentioning usage of batch size ~4096 across multiple GPUs/TPUs. I'm not sure if they also synchronize batch normalization.